# Import from one index to a new index with a persistence model

Tags: elasticsearch, will-paginate, tire

I have an application that has a Nutch crawler sending results directly to an ElasticSearch index created by a Tire Persistence model.

I am looking for the best way to make changes to the index that does not require deleting the index, and then recreating it and re-populating it as the index is the master data source. I've been trying to get the method working where your index is an alias,  then have indexes associated with the alias, and then import from the master index to a new index.

I have been trying to get the `rake environment tire:import CLASS='Applicant' INDEX='index_new'` command to get the job done with this approach, but have not had any success as it fails on the import at first due to an undefined method 'paginate' and then after I defined a 'paginate' method in my model, it fails from an undefined method 'count' which it hits in at tire-0.60.0/lib/tire/model/import.rb:102.

I've been scouring for days looking for the right approach, and I'm not convinced at this point that I'm on the right path at all at this point. I have included my model below for reference. I am using WillPaginate for pagination.

```
class Applicant
  include Tire::Model::Persistence
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks  

  require 'will_paginate'
  require 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
  require 'will_paginate/array'

  index_name 'index'
  document_type 'doc'

 mapping  
    indexes :boost, type: 'string'
    indexes :content, type: 'string'
    indexes :digest, type: 'string'          
    indexes :id, type: 'string'
    indexes :skill, type: 'string'
    indexes :title, type: 'string'
    indexes :tstamp, type: 'date', format: 'dateOptionalTime'
    indexes :url, type: 'string'
    indexes :domain, type 'string'

 property :boost
 property :content
 property :digest  
 property :id
 property :skill 
 property :title    
 property :tstamp  
 property :url
 property :domain

  def self.search(params)
   tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)do
      query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
      filter :term, domain: params[:domain_selected]  if params[:domain_selected].present?
      filter :term, skill: params[:skill_selected]  if params[:skill_selected].present?
      facet "domains" do
        terms :domain
      end 
      facet "skills" do
        terms :skill
      end
    end
  end 

  def self.paginate(params)
   @page_results = WillPaginate::Collection.create(params[:page], per_page, total_entries) do |pager|
     pager.replace(@self.to_array)
   end
   @page_results = @self.paginate(params[:current_page], params[:per_page])
  end
end
```

On a side note but lower priority too me, I've been digging through the code trying to understand why the import needs pagination and it's not clear to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 2 weeks of searching, I found the solution I was looking for. I basically accomplish the same result I was looking for using `Article.create_elasticsearch_index` followed by `Tire.index('original-index-name').reindex 'new-index-name'`. Karmi's tweet here is what led me to the right solution.

https://twitter.com/karmiq/status/185811361069142016

I'm also working on adapting jarosan's work here into working for my situation and will post soon.

https://gist.github.com/3124884

Thanks Michel and Karel.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason you're getting that error is that in your view, I would guess, you're referring to the paginate gem.

First thing to do is either check your view, and strip paginate out of the view and the controller, OR, if you need paginate, do this simple test:

> Your application should load the will_paginate gem. To see if the
>   library has been loaded, open the console for your app and try the
>   following lines:
>
> > > defined? WillPaginate
> > >       ActiveRecord::Base.respond_to? :paginate If any of these lines return nil/false, will_paginate has not properly loaded in your app.

(( from https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Troubleshooting ))

If it fails out, make sure you have the following two lines in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '~> 0.0.6'
```

If that doesn't work for you, let me know, and we'll dig deeper.

Comment: First, thanks for getting back to me. I did try that before and had the response of => "constant" to the first one, and => true to the second line. I just retested and recieved the same result. Note that I am able to successfully import if I am using ActiveRecord when I'm trying to import from a sample database. But with our current architecture, our results are not stored in a database, just an index. So when we switch the Model over to Tire::Model::Persistence, thats when things start to fail.

Additionally, we do need pagination, and it is working correctly for the app.

Thanks again!